# How can I keep browsing my pdf with synctex at the same time as LaTeX is rebuilding it?

Tags: pdftex, forward-inverse-search

As discussed here [pdflatex preview problem: white pdf pages with only hyperref-rectangles visible during compile?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40477/pdflatex-preview-problem-white-pdf-pages-with-only-hyperref-rectangles-visible) when working on my dissertation which takes a long time to compile (even when compiling single chapters with `includeonly` it takes 1..3 minutes to compile with latexmk, I can not view the last version of the pdf to continue working during compiling time which breaks my workflow and makes me wasting time waiting while I could continue editing my document.

I'm working with TeXShop 2.43 on MacOS 10.6.8 with TeXLive 2011. The question is

- how can I keep browsing my pdf (in the last compiled version) as long as pdflatex compiles
- and how can I use `synctex` for jumping from the source file to the pdf and back?

A first suggestion (thanks, jonalv) was

```
latexmk -pdf text.tex && mv text.pdf viewMe.pdf
```

However `synctex` will not be working with the changed file name, especially as it is different from the name of the main file. Is there a way to do it with synctex working?

Comment: It sounds pretty stupid but why not dividing into more pieces until you get reasonable compile times? I can imagine that you might be processing images, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using the following lines for `pdflatex` and for the previewer in my `.latexmkrc` file

```
$preview_prefix="__preview__";
$preview_file = "$preview_prefix%R__.pdf";
$sync_file = "$preview_prefix%R__.synctex.gz";

$pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 %O %S; cp %R.pdf $preview_file; cp %R.synctex.gz $sync_file";
$pdf_previewer = "start okular %O $preview_file > /dev/null 2>&1";
```

If your main file name is e.g. `main.tex`, then it will copy after `pdflatex` has finished processing your tex file the resulting `main.pdf` *and* `main.synctex.gz` into `__preview__main.pdf` and `__preview__main.synctex.gz` and start the previewer with `__preview__main.pdf`. Works fine for me under Linux: by shift+clicking in `okular` I get back to my editor (after setting up `okular` correctly) and further, also for pretty large documents copying is usually fast enough, so that I don't have any lags in viewing.

Comment: +1: I wasn't aware of the `preview_prefix` setting, pretty cool!. Some while ago I tried to getting something like this running with `latexmk`, but miserably failed and therefore switched to a Makefile-based approach.

Comment: @Elmar Zander: Thanks again for your help and sorry for the late reply. I tried it several times, but up to now I was not able to make your approach work with my own latemk setup. Could you have a look at this follow-up question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218183/4009

Comment: @Elmar Zander: hm, I finally tried it successfully and this is really cool - thanks a lot!

Comment: @Elmar Zander: sorry, there is still one problem, I did not notice directly: it seems that the pdflatex compiler modifies the main.tex file and the __preview__ version is the "static" one which I could use during compiling. However, if I use synctex to jump from the source code to the PDF, it jumps to main.pdf and not to the static preview version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac, `TeXShop` Version 2.43 (not sure if this is available on other platforms) seems to exhibit the behaviour exactly as you desire.

After compiling the PDF file is opened and I can use `Sync` to open the corresponding source form the PDF. This feature still seems to function while a new version is begin compiled (if you don't delete the .aux file between subsequent runs). Of course if the source is changed such that the corresponding location of the source is changed all bets are off.

Comment: did you read the linked question and answers here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40477/pdflatex-preview-problem-white-pdf-pages-with-only-hyperref-rectangles-visible Unfortunately with my thesis I can _not_ view the pdf during compiling in TeXShop. For some documents it works for me as you describe, but unfortunately not for the one I'm working on. I assume that it is because of the file size of the pdf (2..>20 MB) which will not be kept in the memory of the pdf viewer.