# How to configure latexmk to compile tmp file and then replace pdf/synctex files?

Tags: latexmk

### history

For the reasons explained in this question [How can I keep browsing my pdf with synctex at the same time as LaTeX is rebuilding it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41378/how-can-i-keep-browsing-my-pdf-with-synctex-at-the-same-time-as-latex-is-rebuild) I want to modify my `latexmk` settings.

### old configuration

Up to now I had the following working configuration for in the `.latexmkrc` file:

```
$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S';
$pdf_previewer = 'open %S';
$pdf_update_method = 0;
$clean_ext = "synctex.gz";

@default_files = ('Diss.tex');
```

I want to apply the changes proposed here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141582/4009 but I am not sure how to mix them with my exiting setup.

### new configuration

I tried

```
$preview_prefix="__preview__";
$preview_file = "$preview_prefix%R__.pdf";
$sync_file = "$preview_prefix%R__.synctex.gz";



$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S'; cp %R.pdf $preview_file; cp %R.synctex.gz $sync_file";
$pdf_previewer = 'open $preview_file';
$pdf_update_method = 0;
$clean_ext = "synctex.gz";

@default_files = ('Diss.tex');
```

but that gives an error and no files are produced:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 10 Nov 2013, version: 4.39.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
      'Diss.pdf'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -recorder  "Diss.tex"'; cp "Diss".pdf __preview__"Diss"__.pdf; cp "Diss".synctex.gz __preview__"Diss"__.synctex.gz'
------------
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'Diss.log'
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'Diss.tex':
   (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'Diss.log'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
It took 0 seconds (0 minutes)
grep: Diss.log: No such file or directory
```

### used system

I'm using `TeXLive 2014` on `MacOS X 10.6`.
My pdf viewer is `Skim.app`

Comment: Try removing the single quote after `%S` in your definition of `$pdflatex`.  That works for me.

Comment: thanks a lot, if you turn this comment into an answer, I can accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the single quote after `%S` in your definition of `$pdflatex`.

From:

```
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S'; cp %R.pdf $preview_file; cp %R.synctex.gz $sync_file";
```

to:

```
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S; cp %R.pdf $preview_file; cp %R.synctex.gz $sync_file";
```