# Can I use synctex to jump to pdf, if pdf file name is different from .tex file name?

Tags: forward-inverse-search, pdfsync

### history

For the reasons explained in this question [How can I keep browsing my pdf with synctex at the same time as LaTeX is rebuilding it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41378/how-can-i-keep-browsing-my-pdf-with-synctex-at-the-same-time-as-latex-is-rebuild) I want to modify my `latexmk` settings.

I tried the changes proposed here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141582/4009:

### new configuration

I tried

```
$preview_prefix="__preview__";
$preview_file = "$preview_prefix%R__.pdf";
$sync_file = "$preview_prefix%R__.synctex.gz";



$pdf_mode = 1;
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S; cp %R.pdf $preview_file; cp %R.synctex.gz $sync_file";
$pdf_previewer = 'open $preview_file';
$pdf_update_method = 0;
$clean_ext = "synctex.gz";

@default_files = ('Diss.tex');
```

### Problem

that works fine so far, but it does not solve my problem, because:

- during compiling the Diss.pdf file is modified and not accessible for reading.
- the `__preview__Diss.pdf` file remains unchanged and can be used for checking the last pdf output (while the new version is compiled)
- when I go to the source code in the .tex files and use `synctex` to jump to the corresponding place in the pdf, it jumps to `Diss.pdf` and **NOT** to `__preview__Diss.pdf` as it should IMHO.

** My Question**

How can I tell `synctex` to jump to the preview pdf instead of the file which has the same name as the .tex master file?

### used system

I'm using `TeXLive 2014` on `MacOS X 10.6`.
My pdf viewer is `Skim.app`